# Go uses Go to parse itself?

Tags: parsing, go, grammar, token

I am starting a class project that regards adding some functionality to Go.

However, I am thoroughly confused on the structure of Go. I was under the impression that Go used flex and bison but I can't find anything familiar in the Go source code.

On the other hand, the directory go/src/pkg/go has folders with familiar names (ast, token, parser, etc.) but all they contain are .go files. I'm confused!

My request is, of anyone familiar with Go, can you give me an overview of how Go is lexed, parsed, etc. and where to find the files to edit the grammar and whatnot?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if they wrote the parser by hand (and hand-rolling a lexer isn't terribly outlandish either). It's actually quite common for mature compilers, and has various advantages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The directory structure:

```
src/cmd/5*   ARM
src/cmd/6*   amd64 (x86-64)
src/cmd/8*   i386 (x86-32)

src/cmd/cc   C compiler  (common part)
src/cmd/gc   Go compiler (common part)
src/cmd/ld   Linker      (common part)
src/cmd/6c   C compiler  (amd64-specific part)
src/cmd/6g   Go compiler (amd64-specific part)
src/cmd/6l   Linker      (amd64-specific part)
```

Lexer is written in pure C (no `flex`). Grammar is written in Bison:

```
src/cmd/gc/lex.c
src/cmd/gc/go.y
```

Many directories under `src/cmd` contain a `doc.go` file with short description of the directory's contents.

If you are planning to modify the grammar, it should be noted that the Bison grammar sometimes does not distinguish between expressions and types.

Answer (score 4):

[lex.c](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/cmd/gc/lex.c)
[go.y](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/cmd/gc/go.y)

Comment: Thank you! Since 8g is the Go compiler on my computer I had thought that the files would be in src/cmd/8g. What do the files in the 8g folder do?

Comment: @user736932: Those sources provide architecture specific code generation. The gc is/should be the arch independent part of the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

The Go compilers are written in c, which is why you need flex and bison.  The Go package for parsing is not used.  If you wanted to write a self hosting compiler in Go, you could use the Go parsing package.

Comment: It even has a depth-first AST walker and a Visitor interface built in. I'm actually looking into writing codegen for the simplest bits of the language (basically, anything that doesn't need the more complex parts of the runtime, like goroutines and garbage collection, so it'll end up being C with a nicer syntax).